# Center Contents of Bootstrap row container

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, center

I have the code below and I'd like to center the "well" elements of the outer "row" div.  I've tried various approaches such as text-align: center (which just centers the text and not the inner DIV elements.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LBtpe/).  The idea is that I get a page of "well" tiles and that after 4 or so it wraps.  But if it is less than 4, they should appear centered on the page.

```
<body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="well span2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    Header
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    Sub Header
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="well span2">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    Header
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    Sub Header
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 80, accepted):

I solved this by doing the following:

```
<body class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6" style="float: none; margin: 0 auto;">
           ....
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just ran a test, should be noted that only the styles need to be added.

Answer (score 232):

With Bootstrap 4, there is a css class specifically for this. The below will center row content:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  ...inner divs and content...
</div>
```

See: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment, for more information.

Comment: latest bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment

Comment: `justify-content-center` also works on containers. It's CSS definition is one line: `justify-content: center !important;` https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/#justify-content

Answer (score 21):

For Bootstrap 4, use the below code:

```
<div class="mx-auto" style="width: 200px;">
  Centered element
</div>
```

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/#horizontal-centering

For Bootstrap 5:

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center">...</div>
```

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/

For Bootstrap 5.3:

```
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-4">
      One of two columns
    </div>
  </div>
```

Ref: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/columns/

Answer (score 18):

Try this, it works!

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>hi 1!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>hi 2!</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <p>hi 3!</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then, in css define the width of center div and center in a document:

```
.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer :

Add this words with the row

```
justify-content-md-center
```

Here's [a link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment/)!
References for getbootstrap.com

Here is the code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
            The content will be centered here
        </div>
 
    </div>
</div>
```