# Difficulty centering content in bootstrap row

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having some trouble with centering three divs inside a row. It appears to stay towards the left. [This bootply shows the row in question](http://www.bootply.com/3TdLfKx5LG#).

If you inspect the row itself with firebug you will notice that the row spans most of the page yet there's a large gap on the right. I have been attempting to have the same distance on the left and right while retaining the size of the two search fields and search button but haven't met with much success.

My search yielded the following which did not appear to help centre the two search fields and search button.

[Center Contents of Bootstrap row container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462535/center-contents-of-bootstrap-row-container)

Any help would be greatly appriciated, thanks

Comment: FYI the link you posted was a question for bootstrap 2.  You are using bootstrap 3.  Also you have an extra `div` that appears to serve no purpose in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
  col-lg-offset-1
```

in the first

```
 <div class="col-lg-4 control-label">
```

is this what you're looking for? http://www.bootply.com/z2ncCLZPXN

Answer (score 1):

Code with `3x col-lg-4` instead of `2 x col-lg-4 + 1x col-lg-2`

*You've space at right because the row in not full, there is an empty space of 2/12 at right.*

Here is the bootply : http://www.bootply.com/73ZYjSx3XE

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how you want to "center" the information.  You could center your content by putting all three elements in a `col-xs-4`, all will take up the same amount of space on an `lg` screen, they will be three across, and they will be centered.

You could try other things if you want to adjust the width of the content.  For example you could add a `col-lg-offset-1` to the first element to shift everything over and leave your widths as they are currently. 
**[Bootply example here](http://www.bootply.com/BS6c9rklhs)**

There are other solutions, but it depends on how you want to display the information.

Answer (score 1):

I would be using the offset feature.

```
col-lg-offset-1
```

Remember Bootstrap is based on 12 total col's. A little math will help get items centered.