# How to center in bootstrap 4 the content in a row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, row

I want to put the content I have(for example image) in center of the row and column.

I tried using justify-content-center, or align-item and text-align: center, but none worked.

I need the image to be in center of the row. Like, if I have 4 columns, i need tohem to be centered on all 4 columns.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Lessons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Stilurile mele -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Fisier spre jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Fisier spre javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js" async></script>

    <!-- FontAwesome - Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png">
                </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Add **text-center** class to each column you want its content to be aligned center.

```
      <div class="col-xl-4 text-center">
          <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png">
      </div>
```

Here is the link to your code with this class added to every column.

[Link](https://codepen.io/ahmadkarimi2009/pen/eYOrBqW)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following CSS on the images:

```
display: block;
margin: 0 auto
```

Full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Bootstrap Lessons</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Stilurile mele -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">

    <!-- Fisier spre jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU="crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Fisier spre javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file.js" async></script>

    <!-- FontAwesome - Icons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
<body>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xl-12">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png" style="margin:0 auto; display:block">
                </div>
        </div>
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png" style="margin:0 auto; display:block">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png" style="margin:0 auto; display:block">
                </div>
                    <div class="col-xl-4">
                <img class="img-fluid" src="https://i.ibb.co/6WddWMk/test.png" style="margin:0 auto; display:block">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap 4 has new class which you can add with row class to center the content.

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
  !-- your content here --!
</div>
```

Hopefully will help you. This is also answered in similar question
[Center Contents of Bootstrap row container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13462535/center-contents-of-bootstrap-row-container)